# How to move D3 graph to initial zoom and at 0,0 position - RESET Graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Hi on click of a button i simply want graph to be at 0,0 position with zoomed out, basically its a reset button.
Is it possible? on which element can i do that?

Will it be :-

```
d3.select('svg').select('g').transition()
.duration(1000).attr('transform', "translate(0,0)scale(1)")
```

But above moved whole graph including x and y axis and just zooms it out. I want only elements inside plotted area to change like lines, dots, values on x and y axis.

Please help.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvxb5t08/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just need to set all back to position (0,0) and scale 1.

You should implement a way to centralize all input controls.

http://jsbin.com/niqara/2/edit?js,output

```
function reset(source) {
  d3.select('g').transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)scale(1)");
  zoomListener.scale(1);
  zoomListener.translate([0, 0]);
}
```

Comment: I see this in JS fiddle, but it doesn't work yet. I need to know what all controls do i need to reset and how? e.g. xaxis, yaxis.. etc

Comment: Great News! I was able to achieve what i wanted using just these 2 lines :
 zoomListener.scale(1);
  zoomListener.translate([0, 0]);

Only thing is it is not updating this on graph immidiately, but i have to drag a bit so graph goes back to 0,0

Comment: great... post an answer when you find the solution, so other people can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve "reset" (moving graph elements to 0,0 and zoom out to initial) using just below lines:-

```
function resetGraph(){
    zoom.scale(1); //Zoom out to this scale
    zoom.translate([0, 0]); //move/drag chart to 0,0 xy position
    zoomed(); //Handler that updates all elements after zoom performed
    slided(); //Optional- to update slider which works to zoom in and zoom out
}
```

Basically all this can go in a function and can be called anywhere or on click of a button to reset graph.